# Connect to Sql Server Compact Remotely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a asp.net mvc with sql Server compact application which hosted in a shared-host, Now my question is: How i can connect to remote Sql ce which hosted in shared-host from my desktop and manage that? or execute entity framework migration scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect to SQL Server Compact remotely, but if you have console access you can use a tool like sqlcecmd or the standalone SQL CE Toolbox to manage the database

Comment: With sqlcecmd or the standalone SQL CE Toolbox i can manage and run scripts Remotely?

Comment: No, you must be logged in to the desktop/command line of the hosted server